# Is it possible to use Lightning Data Service to retrieve all records of a giving SObject and avoid writing a custom AuraEnabled method?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-data-service

I'd like my LWC component to retrieve all records of an SObject type without having to create a custom AuraEnabled method using Lightning Data Services.
Is this possible?

Comment: no one record at a time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

LDS - [lightning/uiRecordApi](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_lightning_ui_api_record), [lightning-record-form](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-form/documentation), [lightning-record-edit-form](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form/documentation) and [lightning-record-view-form](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-view-form/documentation) - are all based for only 1 record .

For simplicity you can write custom apex utils method which accepts parameters like list of fields, object name, query filters etc which can return both SOQL or SOSL query results.

[This](https://github.com/sasank-sfdcdev/public/blob/master/src/classes/datatableController.cls) can be a starting point for creating such method .

```
@AuraEnabled
public static Map<String, Object> fetchDataMap(Map<String, Object> params) {

    String objectName = params.containsKey('objectName') ? (String)params.get('objectName') : null;
    String fields = params.containsKey('fields') ? (String)params.get('fields') : null;
    String queryFilters = params.containsKey('queryFilters') ? (String)params.get('queryFilters') : null;
    String sortBy = params.containsKey('sortBy') ? (String)params.get('sortBy') : null;
    String queryType = params.containsKey('queryType') ? (String)params.get('queryType') : null;
    String soslSearchTerm = params.containsKey('soslSearchTerm') ? (String)params.get('soslSearchTerm') : null;
    Boolean sortAsc = params.containsKey('sortAsc') ? (Boolean)params.get('sortAsc') : false;
    Integer limitRecords = params.containsKey('limitRecords') ? Integer.valueOf(params.get('limitRecords')) : null;

    try{
        //Initial checks
        String limitRecordsStr = String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(limitRecords));

        //Declare query string
        String query;

        //Query initialization for Soql and Sosl
        if(queryType == 'SOQL'){
            query = 'SELECT Id, ' + fields + ' FROM ' + objectName;
        }
        else if(queryType == 'SOSL') {
            query = 'Id, ' + fields;
        }

        //Adding filters
        if(String.isNotBlank(queryFilters)){
            query += ' WHERE ' + queryFilters;
        }

        //Adding order by and limit records
        if(String.isNotBlank(sortBy) && queryType == 'SOQL'){
            query += ' ORDER BY ' + sortBy + (sortAsc?' ASC ':' DESC ');
        }

        if(String.isNotBlank(limitRecordsStr)) {
            query += ' LIMIT ' + limitRecordsStr;
        }

        //Log the query before getting query results from database
        Map<String, Object> returnMap = new Map<String, Object>();
        List<sObject> sObjectsList = new List<sObject>();
        if(queryType == 'SOQL'){
            system.debug('query => '+query);
            sObjectsList = Database.query(query);
        }
        else if(queryType == 'SOSL') {
            query = 'FIND \'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(soslSearchTerm) + '\' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING ' + objectName + '(' + query + ')';
            system.debug('query => '+query);
            sObjectsList = Search.query(query)[0];
        }

        returnMap.put('records', sObjectsList);

        //Log the result
        system.debug('returnMap => '+returnMap);

        return returnMap;     
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        system.debug('Error => '+ex.getMessage());
        throw new AuraHandledException(ex.getMessage());
    }   
}
```